# why using two threads for a counter decreases performance in Java?

Tags: java, python, multithreading

In `python` using two `Threads` for a simple counter program (as demonstrated below) is slower than the program with a single `thread`. The reason given to this  is the mechanism behind `Global Interpreter lock`.

I tested the same in `java` to see the performance. Here again, I see that a single `Thread` out-performs `two-threaded` one with a significant time scale. why is it so?

Here is the code:

```
public class ThreadTiming {

    static void threadMessage(String message) {
        String threadName =
            Thread.currentThread().getName();
        System.out.format("%s: %s%n",
                          threadName,
                          message);
    }

    private static class Counter implements Runnable {

        private int count=500000000;
        @Override
        public void run() {

            while(count>0) {
                count--;
            }
            threadMessage("done processing");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Counter());
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new Counter());

        long startTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t1.join();
        t2.join();
        long endTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Time taken by two threads "+ (endTime-startTime)/1000.0);

        startTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
        Calculate(2*500000000);
        endTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Time taken by single thread "+ (endTime-startTime)/1000.0);
    }

    public static void Calculate(int x){
        while (x>0){
            x--;
        }
        threadMessage("Done processing");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Thread-1: done processing
Thread-2: done processing
Time taken by two threads 0.052
main: Done processing
Time taken by single thread 0.0010
```

Comment: Firstly your code isn't threadsafe, so I'm not positive how to reason about it.

Comment: ThreadSafe doesn't matter here I guess. I am not locking/synchronization on anything nor I need to. If I implemented ThreadSafe, it will definitely slow down..

Comment: I can't see anything that would keep it from being thread safe. Each thread has its own instance of `Counter`. There is nothing shared between them, that I can see.

Comment: I have said this for many thread related questions - making a program multithreaded doesn't magically makes it faster.

Comment: Did you give a chance the second thread to run?

Comment: It is TS, I thought the count was static for whatever reason.

Comment: @Dyrborg: I suppose that is applicable when you want to make Thread safe. Here is more like parallel programming. so I presume it should definitely be faster,unless the spawning new Threads is really time consuming than the calculation performed

Comment: I don't see any JIT warming going on. I think the two threads are warming on JIT and the single thread is then reaping the rewards. This isn't how you micro bench java. Run the tests a few tens of thousands of times first, then run them again and time. Take the average of the second set. Better yet, use Caliper.

Comment: @BoristheSpider:I tried "warming" the JIT with a precalculation by calling the SingleThread method. but the performance difference is still the same (or even higher)

Comment: Threads are designed to work best when they have independant tasks.  You have two highly co-dependent task contending on the same piece of memory.  Not only will it be slow, the answer will be wrong.  You will find the counter does count as much you think it should.

Comment: In short, incrementing is extremely cheap, sharing memory is expensive.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: I don't see a shared `Counter` in the above code. What do you mean by "sharing memory" in this case?

Comment: @PeterLawrey: There is nothing shared. Each thread has its own local variables and does its job..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic answer is you have code the optimiser can eliminate and you are timing how long it takes to detect this.  You are also adding the time it takes to start and stop two threads which could be more than half this time.

The second test doesn't start a new thread, it uses the current one so you just need to wait for it to detect the loop doesn't do anything.

For example you have timed that a single thread can do 1 billion loops in 1 ms.  If you have a 3.33 GHz processor, this would have to do 300 iterations in a single clock cycle.  If this sounds too good to be true, that is because it is. ;)

Comment: I guess the overhead of creating/starting two threads is the limiting factor in this case. otherwise there is no reason why this could be slower. Increasing the loop to `2*5000000000L`, actually increases the differences more..

Comment: @brainstorm For it to be a like for like comparison, try starting and joining just one thread.

Comment: creating a new thread for a single thread process instead of running in `main` slows down by a factor of 2. so the key is here the thread creation/start-up time. while Python enforces GIL mechanism, I don't think Java has any such restrictions

Comment: @brainstorm no, not even if you need it. e.g. your two threads try to increment the same counter. You have to do the thread safety yourself.

Answer (score 4):

Very simple. The single threaded version uses a local variable which hotspot has no problems to reason that it never leaves the scope, hence the whole function is reduced to a nop.

On the other hand proving that the instance variable never leaves scope (hello reflection!) Is much harder and obviously hotspot cannot it here hence the loop isn't removed.

On a general note benchmarking is hard (i count at least three other mistakes that could lead to "wrong" results) and requires tons of knowledge.You are better off using jmh (java measuring harness) which takes care of most things.

Comment: brain storm's benchmark is far too simplistic also to provide any real world performance insight. Python does threading just fine if we are waiting on I/O, or even try PyOpenCL.

Answer (score 2):

@Voo seems to be generally right, as you can see by moving `ThreadTiming.Counter.count` to be a local variable of `ThreadTiming.Counter.run()`.  That eliminates any possibility of non-local references, and the resulting program exhibits much less single-thread vs. dual-thread performance difference.

HOWEVER, that doesn't eliminate **all** the difference.  The timing reported for the dual-thread case is still worse by about a factor of 9 for me.  But if I then swap so that the single-threaded case is measured first, the two-thread case wins by about a factor of 2.

But that, too, is illusory, because the two tests are running different -- albeit similar -- code.  The single-thread case can easily be made to run exactly the same code as the dual thread case:

```
Counter c = new Counter();
c.run();
c.run();
```

(Using the version where `count` is local to `run()`.) If that approach is used then I observe no difference in performance (at the resolution of the measurement) between single- and dual-threaded, regardless of which case is tested first.

As @Voo said, benchmarking is hard.

Answer (score 0):

It just looks like it's from loading each thread and its context into the CPU. It's thrashing. There's probably a more detailed answer waiting to strike, but let's start by posting the basics...

Answer (score 0):

When running two threads, your timer is including the time taken to launch the two threads.  Creating and starting threads has some overhead, and in this case, the overhead is longer than the time to actually carry out the process.